# Conditional Table Creation in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sqlite has the useful "create table if not exists" syntax.

Is there an equivalent in Access, or (as it looks) do I need to build a separate way of checking first?

Comment: Um, what's the point of deleting the tag MS-ACCESS and replacing it with the tag MS-ACCESS?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a table?  If it's for temporary data storage then that's fine otherwise that's usuaally not required.

See the TempTables.MDB page at my website which illustrates how to use a temporary MDB in your app. http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/temptables.htm